# Autocad dll Strong signing error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, autocad

I have built an app using Visual Studio 2012,.Net ver 4.  It runs fine using debug until I try to build or publish it.  I get error messages about AutoCAD dll files needing to be strong signed in order to be marked as a prerequisite if I have the Copy Local property on AcDbMgd.dll or AcMgd.dll set to False as is recommended in the .NET Developer's Guide.  If I set this property to True for these two references, the app builds but giving runtime error "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program".  I've tried removing the references to these two files and deleting out the bin and obj folders with no luck.  I'm using the ObjectARX 2014 SDK for the dll files but I've also tried the dll files included with the AutoCAD 2014 installation with the same bad results.  Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

The AcDbMgd.dll and AcMgd.dll files included with the objectarx sdk are stripped down versions of the ones in your AutoCAD install folder. They contain the signatures but not the working code. It is possible under some circumstances to overwrite your working dlls with the development dlls.
Compare the size of the dlls in question in the objectarx directory to the ones in the acad directory. If they are the same size you may need to do a install repair/reinstall.